# NullPointerException when accessing Autowired Repository

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Relevant section of Java JPA Config File

```
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transManager") @DependsOn("emf")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean(name = "emf") @DependsOn("dataSource")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect");

        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory;
        }
@Bean
    public AppWindow mainBean() {
        return new AppWindow();
    }
```

How I'm wiring the repository:

```
@Autowired
private SomeRepository someRepository;
```

Context: Creating a Java 7 SE program that uses Spring Data for database management.

Problem: I keep getting a NullPointerException when trying to access the repository.

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainBean' defined in config.JpaConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [app.AppWindow]: Factory method 'mainBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at app.App.main(App.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [app.AppWindow]: Factory method 'mainBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at app.AppWindow.loadFromDB(AppWindow.java:355)
    at app.AppWindow.<init>(AppWindow.java:88)
    at config.JpaConfig.mainBean(JpaConfig.java:71)
    at config.JpaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2699e960.CGLIB$mainBean$2(<generated>)
    at config.JpaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2699e960$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d50a1d29.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at config.JpaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2699e960.mainBean(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 13 more
```

Method where NullPointerException is occurring:

```
private List<SomeObject> loadFromDB()
    {return someRepository.retrieveAllByCodeLength(5);}
```

Repository Code:

```
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeObject, Integer> {

    @Query(" from SomeObject o where o.code = :code")
    SomeObject findByCode(int code);

    @Query(" from SomeObject o where o.description = :description")
    SomeObject findByDescription(String description);

    @Query(" from SomeObject o where LENGTH(o.code) = :length ORDER BY o.description")
    List<SomeObject> retrieveAllByCodeLength(int length);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to inject the factory bean. What you could inject is the EntityManagerFactory, or the EntityManager itself, using `PersistenceContext`. That said, You shouldn't have an NPE either. So post the stack trace of the exception, and the relevant code. ALWAYS post the complete exception stack trace when asking about an exception.

Comment: Added Stack Trace, along with the Repository I'm using.

Comment: The exception is thrown in the AppWindow constructor. And you didn't post it.

Comment: I did post it, see "Method where NullPointer is occurring".

Comment: In order to diagnose the problem, I propose you move the code calling the repository class to a `PostConstruct` method, and see if you still have the NPE

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it; changed emf out for entityManagerFactory. Also had to add @Param on the Repository queries. Will update with corrected code later.